# Server for playing videos on android device

Tags: android, html, video-streaming, html5-video

I have Activity with a WebView that loads a page. On that page I have html5 video player. In this player I want videos to be looped as a playlist. The videos will be on the server.

I have two questions:

- How to switch to the next video (almost) gapless?
- What type of server to use for the videos?

Comment: I am not aware of the HTML5 video player. However, regarding the server for videos, you need to use a streaming server which supports encoding videos so as to maintain a uniformity between all videos. Also you need to make sure that the server supports encoding profiles supported by your video player.

Comment: @AjithMemana The videos are in mp4 format. Can you give me some server suggestions for a starting point?

Comment: You can Google and get a lot of options. We were using "Panda stream" for our app. We had both video upload and streaming in our app. Everything worked fine with the Native player in Android.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the following streaming servers.

1. Adobe Media Server
2. IIS Smooth streaming
3. Wowza Server

To switch to the next video, you can create a playlist with any of the servers, and accomplish what you would require.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you tell me some open source servers? I need linux based open source server. I found flumotion server. Do you know is it good or can you tell me some other servers like this?